# MembershipProvider with additional data

Tags: asp.net

I'm wanting to inherit from System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider - but I require more data than just a username, password, and email in registration. (such as birthdate and other such data).

How can I add these paramaters and still use the provider model? I've tried just adding a new CreateUser method, but it won't let me compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I did it was to link a membership entity with a memberinfo entity. Then when a new user is created he/she's required to provide more information.

I'm pretty sure the actual provider doesn't give you any more control than that.